# Can't export 3D model for Sketchfab

Tags: modeling

I made my first model in Blender and wanted to post it on Sketchfab. Unfortunately when I do it, I get this picture instead of what I did in my blender file.
[image] Does anyone knows how to fix it? I tried to upload in .blend and in .fbx it is always the same.

This is how I see it in Blender [image]

[Blend File](https://pasteall.org/blend/a02964ff21cf42debf8e999a3f16e7c6)

Comment: Please upload your Blend file to https://pasteall.org/blend/ so that we can have a look at it. Pack any materials into the file first via File > External Data > Pack Resources.

Comment: Uploaded as you said https://pasteall.org/blend/a02964ff21cf42debf8e999a3f16e7c6

Comment: Someone else is will have to chack that out as I'm not familiar with Sketchfab uploads. The only thing I can see at a quick glance is that you have almost 900 duplicate vertices on three parts of your model. Select all in Object mode, go into Edit mode. Select All again and and M > Merge by Distance and you'll briefly see a message on the bottom status bar saying that around 890 vertices have been merged. I've no idea whether that will make any difference in Sketchfab though.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Sketchfab either, but what I read here: [Sketchfab Help Center on Blender materials](https://help.sketchfab.com/hc/en-us/articles/209143886-Blender-Materials-and-Objects) I guess it's not just uploading, you have to fix the materials manually to get them correct in Sketchfab. Although you're in Eevee, I think the following quotes are relevant for your model, too: "We use the information in Cycles material nodes to infer basic PBR textures and parameters for you. While this simplifies the import process, it will still require some work on your end."

Comment: And this quote: "For more complex Cycles setups (like networks that mix and modify textures etc), we recommend you bake the results before exporting to Sketchfab."

Comment: 1. Don't use a noise texture, bake it to a texture map 2. Bake a diffuse texture, I don't think sketchfab supports mixing 2 maps as diffuse 3. you plugged a normal map into a Bump node, you need to plug it into a Normal Map node.

Comment: Or rather you need to transform your bump map into a normal map (and be careful about texture naming, a normal map isn't the same thing as a bump map)

Comment: Thanks everyone, will try to fix it now!